# change the value after passing each line in the txt file by the value n

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to increase the value after each line traveled in the txt file by a certain amount

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import re

f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
#sys.stdout = open("results.txt", "w")
for i in list(lines):
     if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
        p = str(' '.join(i.split()))
        print(p)
        
     else:
        w = i[3:]
        frst=i[2]
        w = ', '.join(w.split())
        y = i[2]
        y=int(y)+1
        c=np.array([w])
        c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")            
        
        frst=str(frst).replace("[",'')
        frst=str(frst).replace("]",'')
        frst=int(frst)
        c1=np.array(c1)
        c1=np.array([c1]*frst)
        c1=np.transpose(c1)
        

        #this is the part of the code where I edit it
        left=c1+10*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3))
        print(left)
```

demofile.txt

```
<=3 1 2 3 4 #first iteration
<=3 1 2 3 4 #second iteration
```

Each line is one iteration. This is how every line goes through and I work with it. I try to increase each iteration by a certain amount

example

```
left=c1+10*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3)) #first iteration
left=c1+20*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3)) # second iteration
```

my output

1st iteration

```
[[11. 21. 31.]
 [12. 22. 32.]
 [13. 23. 33.]
 [14. 24. 34.]]
```

2nd iteration

```
[[11. 21. 31.]
 [12. 22. 32.]
 [13. 23. 33.]
 [14. 24. 34.]]
```

i need

1st iteration

```
[[11. 21. 31.]
 [12. 22. 32.]
 [13. 23. 33.]
 [14. 24. 34.]]
```

2nd iteration

```
[[21. 41. 61.]
 [22. 42. 62.]
 [23. 43. 63.]
 [24. 44. 64.]]...etc
```

I tried to find the end of the line but I couldn't incorporate it into the code as needed

```
for lines in file:
    n=10
    if lines[-1] == '\n':
       left=c1+n*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3))
       n=n+10
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `p` variable to get output that you want. You can modify your code like that.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import re

f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
#sys.stdout = open("results.txt", "w")
p = 1
for i in list(lines):
     if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
        p = str(' '.join(i.split()))
        print(p)
        
     else:
        w = i[3:]
        frst=i[2]
        w = ', '.join(w.split())
        y = i[2]
        y=int(y)+1
        c=np.array([w])
        c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]          
        
        frst=str(frst).replace("[",'')
        frst=str(frst).replace("]",'')
        frst=int(frst)
        c1=np.array(c1)
        c1=np.array([c1]*frst)
        c1=np.transpose(c1)
        

        #this is the part of the code where I edit it
        left=c1+10*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3))*p
        print(left)
        p +=1
```

Also I changed your code. Maybe it works like that,

```
n=10
for lines in file:
    if lines[-1] == '\n':
       left=c1+n*np.ones((1))*((1,2,3))
       n=n+10
```